# swapping two numbers in ci just google the codings in c program then the codes what i wrote was different

Tags: c

I want to write a program in c to swap two numbers.i just google the codings in  c program then the codes what i wrote was different.There is some kind of misunderstanding i cant figure it out.please someone emphasize my problem,thanks.

in here i took num1,num2,temp as variables.then i assigned temp value to the num1 knowing that that  later that temp get assigned it to value of num2(what i thought line 4 and line 5 will give the line 7 printf as num1 value as num2 due to swapping.then line6 give the line 8 printf as value of num2 to as value of num1.
unfortunately results were different

```
int num1,num2,temp;
    printf("give no 1 and no 2  ");
    scanf("%d %d",&num1, &num2);
   num1=temp;
   temp=num2;
   num2=num1;
 printf("\n After swapping,num1=%d" ,num1);
    printf("\n afterswapping, num2=%d",num2);
```

expected two numbers get swapped , what ever values i gave to variables  i received  output  num1 as  34  and num2 also 34

Comment: Just *read* the code you wrote. Draw boxes on paper that represent the variables and apply the changes step by step. What you have now does not make any sense.

Comment: Also, your program doesn't check the return value of `scanf` which is a bug.

Comment: This should help: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Answer (score 0):

You should do :

```
int num1,num2,temp;
    printf("give no 1 and no 2  ");
    scanf("%d %d",&num1, &num2);
    temp = num1;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = temp;
    printf("\n After swapping,num1=%d" ,num1);
    printf("\n afterswapping, num2=%d",num2);
```

Draw a tracking table and see that what you've wrote is not doing the swap. 
FOA, save one number in the temp variable, then you can run over the value's variable saved with the second num and just after that ,place what you saved in temp to be in num1.

Note you can do it in a more elegant way without the Temp variable :

```
num1 = num1 + num2
num2 = num1 - num2
num1 = num1 - num2
```

Try that!